# On the continuity of this function

Tags: analysis, continuity

I don't understand if my reasoning is correct or if I am missing things...
Consider the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x+2 < e^x \\\\ a & x+2 \geq e^x \end{cases}$$

For which values of $a$ is $f(x)$ continuous?

**Attempts**

I made a sketch of the functions $x+2$ and $e^x$ and I noticed there are two points, call them $x_1, x_2$ for which $x+2 = e^x$ and in particular $e^x \leq x+2$ for $x \in [x_1, x_2]$.

So in this sense I thought to write the function as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in (-\infty, x_1) \cup (x_2, +\infty) \\\\ a & x \in [x_1, x_2]\end{cases}$$

Which now shows there are two points at which the continuity is at risk.
However, being the function well defined at those two points, namely $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = a$, then my request should be that

$$\lim_{x\to x_1} f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_2} f(x) = a$$

Which means $x = x_1$ and $x = x_2$

But the exercise asks me for the values of $a$, hence $a = x_1$ and $a = x_2$.

I don't understand if this is correct or if it's all wrong (and in case why/where). Any help is wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: Very good thinking but you just need the last step to cross the finish line: all this proves that there cannot be any such $a$...

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Ah! Since $a$ cannot assume two different values at the same time (hence it can only be $x_1$ or $x_2$) then the function is not continuous. Is that right?

Comment: Yes I think so. You can try to fit a horizontal segment as part of the plot of $f$ in the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ but it will either be connected to the rest of the graph at $(x_1,x_1)$ or $(x_2,x_2)$ but not both.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you so much!